# Multiple line diagrams in the same ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am creating a line diagrams from this data. Does anybody know how to add another line (with a second set of recall and precision points) in the same diagram?

```
recall11Point    = c(0.2, 0.2, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.8, 1.0)
precision11Point = c(1.0, 0.5, 0.67, 0.5, 0.4, 0.5,0.43,0.38,0.44,0.5)
d = data.frame("Recall" = recall11Point, "Precision" = precision11Point);

# old fashioned plotting
#plot(y=precision11Point, x=recall11Point, type="l")

ggplot(data=d, aes(x=Recall, y=Precision)) +
  geom_line(size=2, colour="red") +
  geom_point(size=10)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
d = data.frame(  "Recall" = c(0.2, 0.2, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.8, 1.0)
               , "Precision" = c(1.0, 0.5, 0.67, 0.5, 0.4, 0.5,0.43,0.38,0.44,0.5)
               ,  "Recall2" = seq(0,0.9, by = 0.1)
               ,  "Precision2" = seq(0,0.9, by = 0.1)
)

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data=d) +
  geom_line(aes(x=Recall, y=Precision), size=1, colour="red") +
  geom_point(aes(x=Recall, y=Precision), size=5, color = "red") + 
  geom_line(aes(x=Recall2, y=Precision2), size=1, colour="blue") +
  geom_point(aes(x=Recall2, y=Precision2), size=5, colour="blue") +
  theme_bw() + 
  theme( panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), panel.grid.major = element_blank() )
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you can create a second data frame `dt2` like this

```
dt2 <- data.frame(Recall=recall11Point+runif(10), Precision=precision11Point+runif(10))
ggplot(data=d, aes(x=Recall, y=Precision)) +
  geom_line(size=2, colour="red") +
      geom_point(size=10)+
          geom_line(data=dt2, size=2, aes(x=Recall, y=Precision), colour="red") +
              geom_point(data=dt2, aes(x=Recall, y=Precision), size=10)
```

or you can create a single data frame and add the `group` variable like this (which is better when using ggplot).

```
df <- rbind(d, dt2)
df$group <- gl(2, 10)

ggplot(data=df, aes(x=Recall, y=Precision, group=group))+
    geom_point(size=2)+
        geom_line(sise=10)
```